# Find every time an event does NOT happen within 1 or fewer days of another

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have one dataframe of transportation, and another dataframe of records at a location. I want to find all instances where someone 1) took transportation and 2) was NOT on record at the location within 0-1 days of the transit.

Below is a simplified example of what I have, and methods I have tried. The method/reason column is not relevant to compare by, but I need it in my actual data, so I included a column in each dataframe.

The trouble is coming in when accounting for 0-1 days within transit. If someone takes transit on 1/4, and is on record at the location 1/5, then that is a non-issue. Even if I add additional date rows to imagine that the person travelled on 1/5 as well, then 1/4 would still show up as an NA when I do the join. Any ideas?

```
library(tidyverse)

Date <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-04","2022-01-04","2022-01-05", "2022-04-06", "2022-04-06")
Method <- c("train","taxi","train","bus","bus","bus", "train", "train")
Person <- c("A","B","C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A")

transportation <- data.frame(Date,Method,Person)

transportation

Date2 <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-05", "2022-05-10")
Reason <- c("x","Y","Z","W", "x")
Person2 <- c("A","B","C", "D", "E")

location <- data.frame(Date2,Reason,Person2)
location

# Possible situations
# Person A rides transport on date x, A is on record at location on date x OR x + 1 : NON-ISSUE
# Person A does not ride transport on date x or x + 1, A is on record at location : NON-ISSUE
# Person A rides transport on date x, A is NOT on record at location on date x & date x + 1 : ONLY POSSIBLE ISSUE
# There may be some scenarios I am not considering that are non-issue, but there is only one possible situation that is problematic - which I want to find

# This WORKS and finds instances of someone traveling to the area, but not being on record at the location
# However, it does not account for the person being at the location on date + 1
location %>% 
  right_join(transportation, by = c("Date2" = "Date", "Person2" = "Person"))

# This works EXCEPT it has a huge flaw - it matches person A at the location 1/1/2022 to person A taking transit on 4/6/2022. 
# That should show up as a flag because person A was NOT at the location 4/6/2022.
location %>% 
  right_join(transportation, by = c("Person2" = "Person")) %>% 
  mutate(Date2 = as.Date(Date2),
         Date = as.Date(Date),
         date_gap = Date2 - Date,
         date_gap = as.double(date_gap)) %>% 
  filter(is.na(date_gap) == TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? Flag people who 1) dont show up (i.e., `is.na`), show up late (i.e., `time > 1`) or are matched with a time previous (i.e., `time < 0`).

```r
library(tidyverse)

transportation |>
  mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date)) |>
  left_join(location |>
               mutate(Date2 = lubridate::ymd(Date2)), by = c("Person" = "Person2")) |>
  mutate(time = as.numeric(Date2 - Date)) |>
  filter(is.na(time) | time > 1 | time < 0)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   Date       Method Person Date2      Reason  time
#>   <date>     <chr>  <chr>  <date>     <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 2022-01-04 bus    E      2022-05-10 x        126
#> 2 2022-01-05 bus    F      NA         <NA>      NA
#> 3 2022-04-06 train  G      NA         <NA>      NA
#> 4 2022-04-06 train  A      2022-01-01 x        -95
```

Comment: This is close, but the output in rows 1 and 4 are not quite what I am looking for. On 1/4 person E took the bus. On 5/10 E was at the location, but these trips are 4 months apart so they are unrelated and are a non-issue. Perhaps person E walked on 5/10. Meanwhile person A on 4/6 took the train, but has no corresponding visit to the location within 0-1 days. This IS a problem, but it is matched with a visit from 3 months ago. Perhaps it is actually fine though and the ones with non NA time need a manual review